# Filtering an embedded array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongodb document that contains an an array that is deeply imbedded inside the document. In one of my action, I would like to return the entire document but filter out the elements of that array that don't match that criteria.

Here is some simplified data:

```
{
   id: 123 ,
   vehicles : [
     {name: 'Mercedes', listed: true},
     {name: 'Nissan', listed: false},
     ...
   ]
}
```

So, in this example I want the entire document but I want the `vehicles` array to only have objects that have the `listed` property set to `true`.

**Solutions**

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution using mongo's queries (e.g. `$unwind, $elemMatch, etc...) but I'm also using mongoose so solution that uses Mongoose is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use aggregation framework like this:

```
db.test312.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$vehicles"},
    {$match:{"vehicles.name":"Nissan"}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id",vehicles:{$push:"$vehicles"}}}
)
```

Comment: How to I keep properties inside the main object? (e.g. {
   id: 123 , name: 'testName',
   vehicles : [
     ...
   ]
})

Comment: Either by adding fields to {$group:{_id:{_id:"$_id",name:"$name"}}, vehic...} or by using {_id:"$_id",name:{$last:"$name"},vehic..}. In first case you need to add {$project:{}} after {$group} to unwrap _id

Comment: Thanks, I was kinda going the second way, but the first seems a bit cleaner

Comment: Actually I've encountered problem with that method: Follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636175/filter-subdocument-array-while-still-returning-parent-data-if-empty

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$addToSet` on the group after unwinding and matching by listed equals true.

Sample shell query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $unwind: "$vehicles"
},
{
    $match: {
        "vehicles.listed": {
            $eq: true
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$id",
        vehicles: {
            "$addToSet": {
                name: "$vehicles.name",
                listed: "$vehicles.listed"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        id: "$_id",
        vehicles: 1
    }
}
]).pretty();
```