# Filter subdocument array while still returning parent data if empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the method from this question [How to filter array in subdocument with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117030/how-to-filter-array-in-subdocument-with-mongodb)

It works as expected except when none of the elements in the array match the test. In that case, I just get an empty array with no parent data.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
 {
  "_id": "53712c7238b8d900008ef71c",
  "dealerName": "TestDealer",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "address": {..},
  "inventories": [
      {
          "title": "active",
          "vehicles": [
            {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef720",
              "createdAt": "2014-05-12T20:08:00.000Z",
              "tags": [
                 "vehicle"
               ],
               "opts": {...},
               "listed": false,
               "disclosures": {...},
               "details": {...}
           },
           {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef720",
              "createdAt": "2014-05-12T20:08:00.000Z",
              "tags": [...],
              "opts": {...},
              "listed": true,
              "disclosures": {...},
              "details": {...}
            }
         ]
     },
     {
         "title": "sold",
         "vehicles": []
     }
  ]
}
```

**TRYING TO DO**

In my query I would like to return the user (document) top-level info (dealerName, email) and a property called vehicles containing all the vehicles in the "active" inventory that have the property listed set to `true`.

**HOW FAR I GOT**

This is my query. (I use Mongoose but use mostly native Mongo features)

```
      {
        $match:
          email: params.username
      }
      {
        $unwind: '$inventories'
      }
      {
        $match:
          'inventories.title': 'active'
      }
      {
        $unwind:
          '$inventories.vehicles'
      }
      {
        $match:
          'inventories.vehicles.listed':
            $eq: true
      }
      {
        $group:
          _id: '$_id'
          dealerName:
            $first: '$dealerName'
          email:
            $first: '$email'
          address:
            $first: '$address'
          vehicles:
            $push: '$inventories.vehicles'
      }
```

**THE PROBLEM**

At first, I thought my query was fine, however, if none of the vehicles are marked as `listed`, the query just returns an empty array. This makes sense since

```
      {
        $match:
          'inventories.vehicles.listed':
            $eq: true
      }
```

Doesn't match anything but I would still like to get the dealerName as well as his email

**DESIRED OUTPUT IF NO VEHICLES MATCH**

```
[{"dealerName": "TestDealer", "email": "test@test.com", vehicles : []}]
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
[]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use $redact instead of $match in this case, like this

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  $redact:{
    $cond:{ 
       if:{$and:[{$not:"$dealerName"},{$not:"$title"},{$eq:["$listed",false]}, 
       then: "$$PRUNE", 
       else: "$$DESCEND" 
    }
  }
})
```

We need first condition to skip top level documents, second condition to skip second level and third one to prune vehicles. **No $unwind needed** in this case!

One more thing: $redact available only in 2.6

Comment: I don't think this will work because `$cond` has to be true for the root and second levels to reach the third level. This query will prune the document at the root level (it has field `dealerName` so `$cond` is `false`).  The only way for this to work would be to drop the first two conditions and add `listed:true` to the root and second levels.