# Mongodb $filter on Embedded Documents, return all collection data?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb and I have a document which return a json like that:

```
{
            "_id": "5ad9a24be78f9d33888d2567",
            "tag": [],
            "active": 1,
            "code": "_CAROT",
            "name": [
                {
                    "lang": "uk",
                    "translation": "carot"
                },
                {
                    "lang": "fr",
                    "translation": "carotte"
                }
            ],
            "season": [],
            "category": [],
            "createdAt": "2018-04-23T07:59:51.261Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-04-23T07:59:51.261Z",
            "__v": 0
```

}

I want to add a filter on the lang, to get only one translation. So I am using aggregate and $filter to do that. This is what I do :

```
db.products.aggregate(
[ {$match: {'name.lang': "fr"}}, 
{$project: { name: {$filter: {
            input: '$name', 
            as: 'item', 
            cond: {$eq: ['$$item.lang', "fr"]} 
           }} 
       }} 
  ])
```

And I get :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ad9a24be78f9d33888d2567"), "name" : [ { "lang" : "fr", "translation" : "carotte" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5add96fedf3aac3d049196ca"), "name" : [ { "lang" : "fr", "translation" : "tomate" } ] }
```

However I would like to get the following result :

```
 {
                "_id": "5ad9a24be78f9d33888d2567",
                "tag": [],
                "active": 1,
                "code": "_CAROT",
                "name": [
                    {
                        "lang": "fr",
                        "translation": "carotte"
                    }
                ],
                "season": [],
                "category": [],
                "createdAt": "2018-04-23T07:59:51.261Z",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-23T07:59:51.261Z",
                "__v": 0
}
```

Basically the default result with just the "fr" result on the "name" field.

Is there a way to do it using **mongoDB** ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_

Comment: Use `$addFields` instead of `$project`. Or of course also include all the other fields in the `$project`. But the former is far easier

Comment: Did you take a look at this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614116/filtering-an-embedded-array-in-mongodb

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation `$unwind` to "*unwrap*" by translation. I means that for each translation value of each document it will create a new document with only this translation value (at the same level, not in a sub document). Then you will have to then filter with `$match` to only keep the "fr" translations.

**Note** you will have to copy each field name to have it in the final result.

Example:

```js
db.products.aggregate([
    { $unwind:  '$name'                                    }, // scalar product by name 
    { $match:   { 'name.lang': 'fr' }                      }, // only keep documents in french
    { $project: { _id: 0, code: 1, 'name.translation': 1 } }  // return code + translation (in french)
])
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? :-)

Comment: Of course, I am editing my answer to feature an example.