# Mongo DB UpdateOne with c#

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

I've got this data in mongodb

```
    {"_id" : "pippo",
    "Rich" : [
        {
            "_id" : "8c9379f1-ba5a-4b43-b7ad-f5fe3bf6f09d",         
            "Appr" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : "8c9379f1-265a-4b43-b7ad-f5fe3bf6f09d",         
            "Appr" : null
        }
    ]},
    
    {"_id" : "pluto",
    "Rich" : [
        {
            "_id" : "8c9379f1-ba5a-4b43-b7ad-f5fe3bf6f09d",         
            "Appr" : null
        },
        {
            "_id" : "8c9379f1-265a-4b43-b7ad-f5fe3bf6f09d",         
            "Appr" : null
        }
    ]},
```

How can i update, with the command UpdateOne, in document "Pippo" the property "Appr" inside the array "Rich" having "_id" 8c9379f1-265a-4b43-b7ad-f5fe3bf6f09d?

thank you

Bruno

**UPDATE**

I try this

```
    var filter = Builders<RichiestaGiornalieri>.Filter.Eq("id", Pippo);
    var update = Builders<RichiestaGiornalieri>.Update.Set("rich.appr", new[] { new Approvazione() { Approvata = true",
    Approvatore = User.Identity.Name,
    DataApprovazione = DateTime.Now,
    id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Note = "" } 
    });
    var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition> { new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<RichiestaGiornalieri>("{'rich.id':'8c9379f1-265a-4b43-b7ad-f5fe3bf6f09d'}") };
    var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = arrayFilters };

    dbRichieste.UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

But i receive this error messagge

```
    MongoBulkWriteException`1: A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors.
The array filter for identifier 'rich' was not used in the update { $set: { rich.appr: [ { DataApprovazione: new Date(1599579246919), _id: "2a5cc55e-70e8-4138-ace2-6b5131cd4a9a", Approvata: true, Approvatore: "Pippo", Note: "" } ] } }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I didn't try nothing becouse i don't hunderstand how to filter array inside document

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614116/filtering-an-embedded-array-in-mongodb

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava the link you gave me it seems a filter for read document.